# Intuition for triangular distribution as difference of uniform distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is there any intuition for the fact that the distribution of the difference of two independent uniform random variables has a triangular distribution?

One line of thought might be to consider the uniform real distributions from [0, 10]. It is readily apparent that the distribution has to be symmetric, and further that it must be first increasing then decreasing, as there are more ways to create, for instance, 5 as a difference of two numbers than there are to create -10 or 10.

However, is there any intuitive way to see that the distribution is triangular rather than any other distribution which is symmetric and has a max around the center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two distributions $X\sim\mathcal U(a;b), Y\sim\mathcal U(c;d)$ then on a plot of $y$ versus $x$, the density function $f_{X-Y}(u)$ will be proportionate to the measure of the length of the segment of that passes through the joint support rectangle $(a..b){\times}(c..d)$ along the line $y=x-u$ .

Clearly, as you said, these segments will be shorter near the corners than those nearer the diagonals.

Note that $X-Y$ will only have a triangular distribution if $\;b-a=d-c\;$ (that is, the joint support is a square interval), otherwise it will have a trapezoidal distribution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with a picture? When you mean plot of $y$ vs. $x$ are you plotting the values of the random variable $X$ and $Y$ or their frequencies against each other?